# Find the average of the values in a string

Tags: r, mean

I have a string that looks like:

```
strg1 <- "18 16 15 12 9 37"
```

I want to find the mean of all of these numbers.

I know I can split the vector by

```
avg1 <- strsplit(strg1, split=' ')
```

and that will give me separate vectors, but I am having troubles finding the `mean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `strsplit` here:

```
mean(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(strg1, " "))))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is

```
rowMeans(read.table(text=strg1))
```

Comment: @李哲源  I saw that.  My first option would be `scan`, but if there are multiple strings, then `strsplit` is preferable.   If the number of elements in the string is large, then reading into a data.frame would be inefficient